# "Windows.System.Launcher" doesn't launch WordPad

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to use `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync()` method with a sample .txt file and it doesn't work - always returns false for WordPad (which is the default program on Windows 8 for displaying .txt files).

However if I change .txt handling settings in Control Panel to Notepad or Word everything works fine, `LaunchFileAsync()` returns true and the file gets displayed correctly.

Any ideas why is this the case?

Comment: You're just calling `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync("MyFile.txt"')`, right? And you're sure WordPad is the default TXT handler?

Comment: This is a Click handler I'm calling:  var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            var success = await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
            if (!success)
            {
                txtBlock1.Text = "File couldn't be opened.";
            }
  WordPad is the default handler for .txt on Windows 8 but it shouldn't matter because Launcher is supposed to launch whatever app is registered as the default for a given file type.

Comment: I can confirm the same happening to me. Unfortunately I don't have an explanation or a solution for you.

Comment: same here.... poking a event logs, but haven't found anything yet

Comment: while I don't have details, I can confirm it's a known issue (WordPad) and indeed will not work in the current release

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to run a desktop application like (notepad, wordpad, internet explorer etc) then go through Process Methods and ProcessStartInfo Class.

```
try
{
// Start the child process.
    Process p = new Process();
    // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Path\To\App.exe";
    p.Start();
}

// Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes,
// both in a minimized mode.

void OpenWithStartInfo()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

    Process.Start(startInfo);

    startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```